# Whcih one is computationally more expensive: Zero knowledge proof or cut-and-choose

Tags: provable-security, zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation

As we know, in order to have multi-party protocol secure against the malicious parties, researchers usually utilise the standard techniques such as zero-knowledge proofs or cut-and-choose technique.

**Question**: Which one of the two is computationally more expensive?

Comment: Zero knowledge and cut-and-choose rather describe the properties of an algorithm than the algorithm itself. The order of the number of primitive operations required is a property of the algorithm and therefore depends on the algorithm chosen. How computational expensive it is depends on the algorithm *implementation*. Still, I presume that one could be *generally* more expensive than the other so I upvoted the question, but please keep above in mind - you're making not one but two jumps: choosing the algorithm and choosing the implementation.

Comment: (If you'd have asked which one is faster than you also depend on the runtime, so hey, it's just two jumps instead of three at least :) )

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you! Mainly I meant complexity wise. Please feel free to edit the question if needed.

Comment: Although I edit questions a lot I try to leave significant changes to the question to the person that asked the question in the first place. This change is too significant to edit in in my opinion.